# Centralizando modal bootstrap

Tags: html5, bootstrap, modal

Tenho uma `modal bootstrap` na minha página `HTML`. Quando abro a modal no browser do computador, a modal aparece da seguinte maneira:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém ao simular a tela de um smartphone, a modal atrás do meu menu `nav`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Abaixo segue o código da modal:

```
<div id="modal-facens" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">FACENS - Faculdade de Engenharia de Sorocaba</h4>
          <i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i> Sorocaba/SP <br>
          <a href="http://www.facens.br/" target="_blank">http://www.facens.br/</a>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>
                Cursando o último ano de Engenharia da Computação 
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn-info btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Gostaria que a modal fosse centralizada em qualquer situação (computador ou mobile). Como posso fazer ?

Comment: Seria bacana se tu utilizasse o Snippet com o CSS junto. Mas ainda antes de fazer isso dá uma olhada em `display: table-cell;` aqui por exemplo: https://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Resolvido.

Alterei o código CSS com o conteúdo abaixo:

```
.modal {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0!important;
}

.modal:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: -4px;
}

.modal-dialog {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

O resultado que eu queria:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]